The bond option formula in Hull cannot be used for corporate bonds
John C. Hull gives the standard Black-76 formula for bond options:
$C = e^{-rt}(FN(d_1)-KN(d_2))$.
This formula cannot be used for corporate (defaultable) bonds.
Let's consider the following example. We have a call option on a bond with excercise in 1Y. The bond is a zero coupon corporate bond, which matures in 1Y immidiately after the option excercise time. Flat risk free rate is $r=0.05$, risky rate (bond yield) is $y=0.08%$. The notional is $N=100$, the strike is $K=0$ (we get the bond for free). Let's assume that the volatility is close to zero either.
According to Hull $C=e^{-rt}(F*1-0*0)=100*e^{-0.05*1}$.
This is obviously wrong for corporate bonds, as we carry the credit risk and the price of this call should equal the price of the risky bond itself. No one is going to magically replace this bond with a good one. If the risky bond defaults, we get the defaulted bond.
So the correct price seems to be $C = e^{-yt}FN(d_1)-e^{-rt}KN(d_2) = 100*e^{-0.08}$ (my guess).
Does anybody know more about the Black-76 bond option forumla for defaultable (corporate) bonds and its greeks?

I think your guess is about right. Use a continuous dividend yield to change the forward of your asset (which is given) without touching the discount. But at the same time, I doubt, the distribution of your underlying is log-normal if a default happens. For this reason, I think you should write down exactly what happens in case of a default.

You should distinguish options that knock out on credit event versus ones that don't. Corporate bond options don't trade much these days, but when they do, both versions happen OTC.

These options usually trade embedded in the bond itself, i.e. as callable/puttable bonds and they are rather common. Credit even will probably knock them out, though not by design, but because the issuer is failing to meet its obligations (including the put option).

So, what are the exact cash flows if there is a default? Is a recovery paid? How much? When? And what about a put option?

For simplicity we can assume that nothing is paid, nor executed after the default event. On the other hand, even when we have a government bond the Hull's formula is not exact, because we need to discount the bond using the FI government curve and cash with MM OIS curve.

Myabe I am missing something, but the forward price for a bond with current price $P_t$ is $F_t = P_t e^{r(T-t)}$. Hence $e^{-r(T-t)}F_t = P_t$, which is the current price of the bond. That seems to make sense to me for $K=0$. The default risk is already priced into $P_t$. More generally, for defaultable bonds you can use a jump-to-default model for bond option  pricing. For $K=0$ the bond option price is the same under jump-to-default model and 'normal' Black-Scholes.

In a world with multiple discounting, you need to be careful how you discount each payment.
For instance: is the option cash settled or physically settled. Is it collateralised or not? What do you mean by risk free rate?
For the BS formula, what really matters is the Forward of the asset, as you can read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Alternative_formulation
Then, the problem of how to discount is not BS-specific, and it is very possible that you will have to discount the bond part (with $y$) differently than the cash part (with $r$).
On the other hand, it might be interesting to analyse the default model, you mentioned, where default affetcs everything.
In this model, there is a single discount rate ($r$) and a default intensity ($\lambda=y-r$).
You can split every contract as
$call(T) = \mathbb{E}[0 \, if \, \tau \le T] + \mathbb{E}[call \, if \, \tau > T]$
Where $\tau$ is the default time, which is exponential and independent, so
$call(T) = \mathbb{E}[call \, | \, \tau > T] \mathbb{P}[\tau > T]$
and since $\mathbb{P}[\tau > T] = e^{-\lambda \, T}$
this acts like an extra uniform discounting applied to everything.
But, before going into options, make sure you are happy with pure discounting, so start with contracts like $(S-K)$, not $(S-K)^+$, and only then move to options.

I saw in Quantlib the knock out on default flag in blackOptionEngine – https://rkapl123.github.io/OREAnnotatedSource/qle/class_quant_ext_1_1_black_bond_option_engine.html#a50f155105fb4224c9033d173a070e1e1
I had not time to look through it thoroughly, but it seems that you are right, and there are two cases:
[1] callable bond (we assume knock out);
[2] option trade with the 3rd party (no knock out).
In the first case everything is under the survival probability (h). In the second case QL splits it into a regular option and an option on recovery value.

[2] (not embedded) option traded OTC with 3rd party may or may not have the knock out on credit event language.

We already have an appropriate accepted answer. Still, I would like to reformulate it in my own words.
The question seems to assume that $F=N=100$. This can't be correct (unless the terms are such that a credit event invalidates the option), nobody would buy this bond on a forward basis at par because then they would expose themselves to an unacceptable credit risk. Current market price of the bond is $P=N\cdot e^{-yt}$, and the forward price on a no-arbitrage basis will be $F=P\cdot e^{rt}$. Then the Black formula checks out.

The 2 answers offer very different models to handle the default. They agree on the 0-strike-call, but will differ on the rest. The OP, should analyse carefully the product / market to select the most appropriate solution.
